# Mockito throws NPE when using when

Tags: java, spring, junit, mockito

I am currently stuck on a problem using Mockito and I can't find a solution.

This is my method I want to test:

```
 @Override
public WeatherData getData(String wmoId, String location) {
    // Creates a specific csv mapper
    CsvSchema schema = factory.createEmptySchemaWithHeaderAndCommaSeperator();
    CsvMapper mapper = factory.createCsvMapper();
    MappingIterator<WeatherData> order = factory.createNullMappingIterator();
    try {

        order = mapper.readerFor(WeatherData.class).with(schema)
                .readValues(factory.createBufferedInputStream(factory.createWmoUrl(wmoId)));
        WeatherData current = order.readAll().get(2);
        current.setStationName(location);
        return current;
    } catch (Exception e) {

        return createErrorWeatherData(location);
    } finally {
        try {
            order.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {

        }
    }
}
```

And this is my current test class

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class WeatherDataServiceImplTest {

@InjectMocks
WeatherDataServiceImpl service;

@Mock
Factory factory;

@Mock
CsvSchema schema;

@Mock
CsvMapper mapper;

@Mock
BufferedInputStream stream;

@Mock
MappingIterator<Object> iterator;

@BeforeEach
public void setup() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}

@Test
void testGetDataWithInvalidStreamReturnsErrorObject() throws Exception {
    lenient().when(factory.createCsvMapper()).thenReturn(mapper);
    lenient().when(factory.createEmptySchemaWithHeaderAndCommaSeperator()).thenReturn(schema);
    lenient().when(factory.createNullMappingIterator()).thenReturn(null);
    when(mapper.readerFor(WeatherData.class).with(schema).readValues(stream)).thenReturn(iterator);
    WeatherData data = service.getData("id", "location");
    // assertEquals("location", data.getStationName());

}

}
```

Now the problem is that whatever I do I always receive a `NullPointerException` for the

> when(mapper.readerFor(WeatherData.class).with(schema).readValues(stream)).thenReturn(iterator);

I am new to `Mockito` and testing so I hope you can help me here.

Thanks!

Comment: You need to individually mock the calls to `readerFor`, then for `with` and then for `readValues`, you cannot mock them in one go (as far as I know).

Comment: Yes. `mapper` is mock, calls of its methods return mock objects, so `mapper.readerFor(WeatherData.class)` really equals `null`. You can construct a chain of objects and mock all of them and for all create `when().thenReturn()`

Comment: What is content of ```mapper.readerFor``` function?

Comment: What is content of ```mapper.readerFor``` function? what is return type?

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable [deep stubbing](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.6.9/org/mockito/Answers.html#RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS) for chained function calls to work,

Just replace,

```
@Mock
CsvMapper mapper;
```

with

```
@Mock(answer = RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS)
CsvMapper mapper;
```